# Permission denied error while Creating new File | Android

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I am trying to create a image file to external storage to share it. but while trying following code I am having some error

```
        var icon: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.namelogo)

        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "image/*"
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val path = File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg"

        val f = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), path)
        try {


            if (!f.parentFile.exists())
                f.parentFile.mkdirs()
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile()
            f.createNewFile()
            val fo = FileOutputStream(f)

            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("path = ", "+ $path " + e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/IronyBalls/temporary_file.jpg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"))
```

Till now I found solutions only to use

```
if (!f.parentFile.exists())
      f.parentFile.mkdirs()
if (!f.exists())
      f.createNewFile()
```

and

to set permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

that I have already used.But still gettig error as below
in **Error Tab**

> E/path =: + /temporary_file.jpg java.io.IOException: Permission denied

and in **info tab**

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
>
> W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
>
> W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.irony.balls.MainActivity$onCreate$8.onClick(MainActivity.kt:277)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5611)
>
> 10-15 20:33:17.912 29759-29759/com.irony.balls 
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22276) 10-15 20:33:17.912
>   29759-29759/com.irony.balls
>    W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 10-15 20:33:17.912
>   29759-29759/com.irony.balls 
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-15 20:33:17.912
>   29759-29759/com.irony.balls 
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 10-15 20:33:17.912
>   29759-29759/com.irony.balls W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195) 10-15
>   20:33:17.912 29759-29759/com.irony.balls W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-15 20:33:17.912
>   29759-29759/com.irony.balls W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
>
> 10-15 20:33:17.912 29759-29759/com.irony.balls W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)

Comment: What is your `targetSdk`?

Comment: @H.Brooks `targetSdk` is 26

Comment: Yes then you will need runtime permissions, the work around would be to change your `targetSdk` to 23. Since 24 runtime permissions are required.

Comment: thanks @H.Brooks it helped me

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is working on Android 6 or higher have you already requested runtime permissions?

See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html for more details.